# stocks quantity only decreasing not increasing

Tags: python, django

After updating the data, the stocks. Quantity is only decreasing does not matter if we only increase the quantity or decrease the quantity. I want when we update the data the stocks quantity will also be updated for ex-, we increase 2 points then only 2 quantities will be decreased. suppose we have 5 unit of shoes in cart and stocks have 10 quantities left so if we increase 2 so the total quantity will in cart 7 and left quantity in stocks will be 8 quantity shoes and if we decrease 3 quantities so the total quantity in cart will be 4 and total quantity in stocks are 11.

For ex-, we increase 2 points then only 2 quantities will be decreased. suppose we have 5 unit of shoes in cart and stocks have 10 quantities left so if we increase 2 so the total quantity will in cart 7 and left quantity in stocks will be 8 quantity shoes and if we decrease 3 quantities so the total quantity in cart will be 4 and total quantity in stocks are 11.

I just need the logic.

Hope you guys get that!

views.py

```
def supplier_edit(request, id):
    try:
        product = Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
        if product.user == request.user:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                product.product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
                product.product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
                if 'image' in request.FILES:
                    product.image = request.FILES.get('image')
                product.quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
                product.category = request.POST.get('category')
                product.save()

                # Update stock quantity

                messages.success(request, "Product Updated Successfully")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit_stocks', args=[product.id]))
            return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_edit.html', {'products': product})
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, "Some Error Occurred", e)
        return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_edit.html', {'products': product})
```

edit.stocks.views

```
    def edit_stocks(request, id):
        product = Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
        stocks = Stocks.objects.get(product_name=product.product_name)
       
        difference =  stocks.quantity - product.quantity 
        print(difference)
        print(product.quantity)
        # if stocks.quantity >  0:
        #     stocks.quantity - difference
        # else:
        #     stocks.quantity + difference
        stocks.quantity = difference 
        print(difference)
        print(product.quantity)
        stocks.save()
    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('supplier_dashboard'))


    models.py
```

stosks.model

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
        product_name = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES2,max_length=100)
        quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=100)
    

    def __str__(self):
         return self.product_name
```

I just need the logic.

Hope you guys get that!

Comment: as for me you should do all directly in `supplier_edit`, not in `edit_stocks` because it doesn't waste time for redirecting

Comment: do you use negative values (like `-2`) when you decreasing `product` ? Or you would have to send extra information -  ie. `("increase", 2)`, `('decrease", 2)`

Comment: Why does the supplier care what is in customers' carts? If a supplier delivers goods, they're normally added to stock. If customers put goods in carts, there's less stock available but the total amount of goods that the business has doesn't change until the goods are actually sold. Internet retailers are not going to distinguish between goods on the shelves and goods out the back. The name "supplier" might be confusing.